# Не работает аутентификация в Postman

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, postman

Имеется метод, в котором есть аннотация аутентификации

```
@PostMapping("/{restaurant}")
    public Vote vote(@PathVariable("restaurant") Restaurant restaurant,
                     @RequestParam("dateTime") String dateTime,
                     @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        log.info("add vote of user {} for restaurant {}", user.getId(), restaurant.getId());
        return voteService.vote(restaurant, user, dateTime);
    }
```

Я делаю POST-запрос через POSTMAN с предварительно заданным BasicAuth:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но после отправки запроса юзер выходит задан как null
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить, чтобы пользователь считывался? в базе такой пользователь присутствует

Comment: Вы должны сами написать авторизацию пользователя. Сюда `@AuthenticationPrincipal User user` спринг положит объект авторизованного пользователя, если это есть конечно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616386/spring-security-authenticationprincipal